# Django copy/paste Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-orm

What is the Django way to copy and paste Queryset except iterating over records and cloning/saving?
E.g. a set of records from table A needs to be selected, some field updated and records inserted back to the original table? A sample use case is adding subscribers from mailing list A to mailing list B.
Should it be just a loop iterating over QuerySet and cloning/saving record by record, or there is
some method for group operation?

Comment: "is some method for group operation?" I don't think so. "Should it be just a loop iterating over QuerySet and cloning/saving record by record" that looks like 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.4 has [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) method that does his job in 1 sql query

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you want to clone or copy these records - that's something you should avoid in a normalized database anyway.

If you just want to update a single field, then you can do that with the `update` queryset method:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(mailing_list=list_a).update(mailing_list=list_b)
```

If you're talking about adding them to a different M2M relationship, then you can do that simply:

```
mailing_list_b.users.add(*MyModel.objects.filter(mailing_list=list_a))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.3 the solution is to iterate QuerySet and create copies like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy
old_obj = deepcopy(obj)
old_obj.id = None
old_obj.save()
```