# Django - copy and insert queryset clone using bulk_create

Tags: django

My goal is to create a clone of a queryset and then insert it into the database. 
Following the suggestions of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911416/django-copy-paste-queryset), I have the following code:

```
qs_new = copy.copy(qs)
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(qs_new)
```

However, with this code I run into `duplicate primary key` error. As for now, I only can come up with the following work-around:

```
qs_new = copy.copy(qs)
for x in qs_new:
   x.id = None
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(qs_new)
```

**Question**: Can I implement this code snippet without going through loop ?

Comment: Which Django version and which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Can't think of a way without loop, but just a suggestion:

```
# add all fields here except 'id'
qs = qs.values('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
new_qs = [MyModel(**i) for i in qs]
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(new_qs)
```

Comment: Emm...Can you please clarify what makes this approach more efficient than my code?

Comment: I don't think your approach would work. First `copy.copy` would return a shallow copy of a list and you don't need that. Secondly, even you set `id` for each one as `None` which would be correct if call `save()` on each of them, `bulk_create` wouldn't look at that, so you might still have `duplicate key` error. I can't verify my theory so can you verify that?

Comment: No, my code is working. This is entirely an issue of efficiency

Comment: I was surprised about it but maybe I'm wrong, so then it doesn't matter. Even python list comprehension is faster than `for` loop, it's kind of trivial compare to how heavy the database operations would be here.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `bulk_create` behaves differently depending on the underlying database. With Postgres you get the new primary keys set:

> Support for setting primary keys on objects created using
>   bulk_create() when using PostgreSQL was added.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create

You should, however make sure that the objects you are creating either have no primary keys or only keys that are not taken yet. In the latter case you should run the code that sets the PKs as well as the bulk_create inside `transaction.atomic()`.

Fetching the values explicitly as suggested by Shang Wang might be faster because only the given values are retrieved from the DB instead of fetching everything. If you have foreign key relations or m2m relations you might want to avoid simply throwing the complex instances into `bulk_create` but instead explicitly naming all attributes that are required when constructing a new `MyModel` instance.

Here an example:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    name = TextField(...)
    related = ForeignKeyField(...)
    my_m2m = ManyToManyField(...)
```

In case of `MyModel` above, you would want to preserve the ForeignKey relations by specifying `related_id` and the PK of the related object in the constructor of `MyModel`, avoiding specifying `related`.

With m2m relations, you might end up skipping `bulk_create` altogether because you need each specific new PK, the corresponding original PK (from the instance that was copied) and the m2m relations of that original instance. Then you would have to create new m2m relations with the new PK and these mappings.

```
# add all fields here except 'id'
qs = qs.values('name', 'related_id')
MyModel.objects.bulk_create([MyModel(**i) for i in qs])
```

---

Note for completeness:
If you have overriden `save()` on your model (or if you are inheriting from 3rd party with custom save methods), it won't be executed and neither will any `post_save` handlers (yours or 3rd party).

Answer (score 0):

I tried and you need a loop to set the id to None, then it works. so finally it may be like this:

```
    qs_new = copy.copy(qs)
    for q in qs_new:
        q.id = None
        # also, you can set other fields if you need
    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(qs_new)
```

This works for me.